# Fuzzy logic search for full names

Tags: sql-server, fuzzy-search, arangodb

I'm looking for a search engine able to use fuzzy logic algorithms to find matches over a million hotel name records. The idea is to be able to find/suggest hotel names if the input is misspelled or is not in the same order as expected.

I've tried myself by building a FOXX application with ArangoDB using clj-fuzzy library.
The freetext collection applies one algorithm (Metaphone, Double Metaphone, Soundex, NYSIIS, Caverphone, Cologne Phonetic or MRA codex) over each entry and stores in a code attribute. A FULLTEXT index is created over that field and this AQL query is used:

```
/*
Example using doubleMetaphone
-----------------------------
Hotel: Four (FR) Points (PNTS) By (P) Sheraton (XRTN) Daning (TNNK)
Input: Sheraton (XRTN) Points (PNTS)
*/
for h in FLATTEN(UNION(
    (return FULLTEXT(fte_hotels, "fullcode", "XRTN")),
    (return FULLTEXT(fte_hotels, "fullcode", "PNTS"))
))
let score = (CONTAINS(h.fullcode, "XRTN") && CONTAINS(h.fullcode, "PNTS") ? 10:0) +
            (CONTAINS(h.fullcode, "XRTN") ? 1:0) +
            (CONTAINS(h.fullcode, "PNTS") ? 1:0)
sort score desc
limit 10
return { hotel: h, score: score }
```

**EDITED:**
Any other suggestions on how to implement the same with Sql Server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did so far looks good. If you want to do a fuzzy search for words, then you have to do some preprocessing of words using a specialized algorithm.

A slight optimization the query: you could also look for both search items in a single call to `FULLTEXT` if you prefer that.

The following block

```
for h in FLATTEN(UNION(
    (return FULLTEXT(fte_hotels, "fullcode", "XRTN")),
    (return FULLTEXT(fte_hotels, "fullcode", "PNTS"))
))
...
```

should be convertable into the following slightly simpler expression:

```
for h in FULLTEXT(fte_hotels, "fullcode", "XRTN,|PNTS")
...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the optimization. The FOXX app process the input terms and generates the AQL code so your suggestion is really great!.

Comment: HI, I'm following your approach, thanks. Do you know why is this giving me an error: `return FULLTEXT(FULLTEXT(fte_hotelall,"doubleMetaphone","KRTN"),"doubleMetaphone","HTL") ` ? Error: invalid argument type used in call to function 'INTERNAL()'. Thanks

Comment: I think this is due to how `FULLTEXT` is being called: in the inner invocation, it is called with a collection name `fte_hotelall` but in the outer invocation it is given a list of results. I think the first parameter to fulltext needs to be a collection always.